# Date Time Picker with Dynamic Time Slots

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, appointment

I am trying to create an appointment booking system using a calender interface. Currently I am using JQuery/datetimepicker which integrates into Bootstrap 4 - tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.

I am using an AJAX call which provides me with a range of available dates & times in JSON format. There is usually multiple time slots (in hour intervals) in one day for a user to choose from.

Currently I am able to set the dates dynamically using the enableDates option and formatting the array fetched from the AJAX call. However I am not able to specify time slots for a user to choose from.

Searched far and wide for such functionality however there doesn't seem to be a solution for my problem.

Does anybody have an elegant solution for an appointment calender to which only available date (AND TIME!) slots are shown for booking?

I have tried fullcalender.io which does not allow for appointment slots to be set and restricted. Also tried other jquery plugins but I must be missing something.

Comment: SO is about programming issues Lee. Instead of seeking for recommendation, which will end by closing your question, you should post your (relevant) code and ask for solution.

Comment: Ah apologies. I ended up going with FullCalendar.io and leveraging the data using ajax, looping through the event date & time using JS forloop. The dates and events need to be set as an array before including into FullCalendar otherwise it will crash.